# Jinja2 expression: if is not defined or defined but set to false

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible, jinja2

How to achieve this in Jinja 2 template (I am using Ansible/vagrant setup):

**if var is not defined or if it is defined but set to false**
I have those items:

```
vhosts:
  - { host: "abc.dev" }
  - { host: "xyz.dev", ssl: false }
```

And I have this template:

```
{% if item.ssl is none %}
  # do something
{% endif %}
```

So by default ssl is true unless it is written `ssl: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `default` filter:

```
{% if item.ssl | default(true) %}
  # do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: No, `default` is exactly for undefined attribute. I bet some other line throws this exception.

Comment: Sorry my bad! this was another not related issue: your solution works Thanks!